# AttributeError: 'PiRGBArray' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv, dlib, imutils

I'm trying to get the solution Pi-camera with opencv by the problem.Solvers, but get a  AttributeError:  'PiRGBArray' object has no attribute 'shape' Thanks for the help.

> frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 69, in resize
>       (h, w) = image.shape[:2] AttributeError: 'PiRGBArray' object has no attribute 'shape' That's a problem

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
from imutils import face_utils
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import numpy as np
import imutils
import dlib
import cv2
import time



camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))


def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):
    A = distance.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
    B = distance.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])
    C = distance.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])
    ear = (A + B / (2.0 * C)
    return ear

thresh = 0.22
threshs = 0.18
frame_check = 120
detect = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predict = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

(lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_68_IDXS["left_eye"]
(rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_68_IDXS["right_eye"]

flag=0

while True:
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture,format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        subjects = detect(gray, 0

        for subject in subjects:
        shape = predict(gray, subject)
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
        leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
        rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
        leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
        rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)
        ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0
        leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
        rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        if ear < thresh:
            flag += 1
            print(ear)
            print(flag)
            if flag >= frame_check:
                print('asd')

                cv2.putText(frame, "****************danger****************", (10, 30),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                cv2.putText(frame, "****************save my life****************", (10,325),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                if ear > threshs:
                    flag += 1
                    if flag >= frame_check:
                         print('asd')

                cv2.putText(frame, "****************danger****************", (10, 30),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                cv2.putText(frame, "****************save my life****************", (10,325),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)


        else:
            flag = 0
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    raw.truncate(0)
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> Output of Code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/home/pi/pppp.py", line 41, in <module>
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 69, in resize
        (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    AttributeError: 'PiRGBArray' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors - they are impossible to run or search through. Kindly click `edit` under your question and update it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I resolved @MarkSetchell

Comment: Surely you had to `import` some modules? Please make sure you provide a **Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example** as required by Stack Overflow rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I understand already, I am a new user and thank you for the advice. And you have a solution code Of me? @MarkSetchell

Comment: I am guessing that the PiRGBArray/frame that you are passing to `imutils.resize()` is not a Numpy array. There is a lot of very distracting stuff in your code about eyes, contours, playing music... you need to work a bit more on the **Minimal** aspect of your code. Sorry to be picky but if you want folks to help you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try. @MarkSetchell